# About the definition of the word “study”

Tags: meaning

I and some friends were debating about whether the following question is correctly formed or not.  Are the multiple choices are accurate and suitable for the question? We all agree that answer number “4” is the correct answer, however ,we are wondering about answer number “3”. We believe that when someone is studying , he/she is trying to get information about something. We believe it is a possible answer.

The question is:
What is the definition of the following word:
Study

1. easy to see, hear, or understand
2. to give or be a part of something with other
   people
3. to get or discover information about something
4. Research project
5. something you bought
6. say something is good

Comment: #3 would be correct as a definition of *to study*, but not study. By itself, study does mean *discover information*.

Comment: That makes the question dependent on whether bare infinitives and to-infinitives should be kept separate in definitions, @Yosef. Older dictionary definitions blurred the distinction, so the insistence on precision here is questionable. I'd say the question needs refining.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the question is when it uses the definite article: "What is **the** definition..." Very few words have only one definition. The question doesn't specify the part of speech. Answer 4 is appropriate if *study* is a noun. And yes, answer 3 is absolutely true if it's a verb. And there are many other possible definitions (e.g. a room dedicated to reading and writing).

This is one of the many times that a test or other teaching resource offers *a* right answer when there are in fact other possible right answers. (It's a particular problem when the multiple-choice offerings include one of the other possible right answers, without acknowledging it.)

Comment: Also there's a difficulty in asking here, a public area, when the context of the specific teacher and test and the lessons around that for the student may be associated with a single intended answer.   Also, [ell.se] may be a more appropriate place for this kind of question.

Comment: As @Yosef  Baskin says, '**_to_** study' means 'to get or discover information about something', though a question involving such nit-picking is unfair, requiring candidates to second-guess the finickiness of the examiners.